# hibernate unable to read entry that was saved by another server

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am having a dropwizard project hosted on 2 servers for high availability. However the entry created by one server sometimes can't be found by the other server. Typically the other server tries to get the entry after 2 to 3 minutes. 
On retrying after some time, say 1 hr, I can get the entry.
Attaching the code for persisting and getting the entry.

```
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.getTransaction().setTimeout(GiftcardConstants.DATABASE_TIMEOUT);
        try {
            session.save(giftcardBookingEntity);
            if(session!=null && session.getTransaction() != null){
            log.info("committing transaction");
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } else {
            log.error("error in database commit");
        }
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Error in persisting giftcard entity", e);
            return false;
        }
        finally{
            if(session != null) {
                log.info("Closing session");
                session.close();
            } else {
                log.error(" error in closing database session");
            }
        }
```

for getting the entry the code is as follows.

```
        try {
            Query query = session.createQuery("FROM GiftcardBookingEntity GB WHERE GB.id is :id");
            query.setLong("id",id);
            return (GiftcardBookingEntity) query.uniqueResult();
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Error in retrieving entry from database", e);
            return null;
        } finally{
            if(session != null) {
                log.info("Closing session");
                session.close();
            } else {
                log.error(" error in closing database session");
            }
        }
```

GiftcardBookingEntity is a class that is not related to any other class. Also I am just connected to a master server of mysql.

If the entity is persisted by server 1 and the get call is from server 2, one out of 20 times I am unable to get any entity. There are no error logs, just that the entity is null. 
If i retry manually after an hour everything works fine.

I am not sure its a hibernate issue or an issue with mysql server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you set a caching level for hibernate?

Comment: i have used the defaults. no 2nd level cache is being used

Answer (score 0):

Level 1 cache in hibernate is active by default

try clearing it with `session.clear()`

you can also try

`session.refresh(entity)` or `entityManager.refresh(entity)` (if you use JPA) will give you fresh data from DB.

Comment: I have made the changes. will update in a few days if the issues have ceased. Thanks

Comment: Does not help. :(

Comment: no. I finally had to implement AbstratDao from dropwizard. I needed control of the transaction but the trasactions were not always flushed.